# JQuery POST values not updating the database

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, wordpress

This is a relatively simple wordpress plugin allowing users to vote on items in a list. The code below is supposed to do the following:

1. Add the shortcode action [Working]
2. Create the form to allow users to post new values to a list (to be displayed by the shortcode) [Working]
3. Handle the form values [Working]
4. Create the Javascript and JQuery to reload the page on certain clicks [Working]
5. Execute an AJAX callback function that updates the database. **[Not Working]**

The JQuery has a success function, which is triggered by the event. However, no new values are sent to the database, leading me to believe there is something wrong with either: A) the variables passed by the POST function, B) the PHP which retrieves the POST values, or C) the call to the AJAX function.

I never know where to put the quotes and colons in an AJAX function in JQuery. I believe I'm trying to pass "object literals" to the callback function through POST. I'm lost as to why this is not working.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
*
*
SHORTCODE
*
*
*/

add_shortcode('list-up-down', 'cb_lud_scfunc');

function cb_lud_scfunc() {
global $wpdb;
$cb_lud_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$cb_lud_table = $cb_lud_prefix . 'cb_list_up_down';
$cb_lud_homeurl = home_url();
$cb_lud_upimg = plugins_url('list-up-down/images/up-arrow.png', _FILE_);
$cb_lud_downimg = plugins_url('list-up-down/images/down-arrow.png', _FILE_);
$cb_lud_sample_query = $wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM '.$cb_lud_table);
$cb_lud_field1_name = $wpdb->get_col_info('name',1);
$cb_lud_field2_name = $wpdb->get_col_info('name',2);

/*
CREATE THE FORM
*/
//Create the form to allow users to add records
    $cb_lud_sc_form = '
        <form id="list-up-down-form" name="list-up-down-form" action="" method="post">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><h2>'.$cb_lud_field1_name.':</h2><input id="field1_input" name="field1_input" type="text"></input></td>
                <td><h2>'.$cb_lud_field2_name.':</h2><input id="field2_input" name="field2_input" type="text"></input></td>
                <td valign="bottom"><input name="add_record" type="submit" value="Add Record" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        ';

/*
DEFINE HOW THE FORM HANDLES THE INPUT(S)
*/
$field1_data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['field1_input'], ENT_QUOTES);
$field2_data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['field2_input'], ENT_QUOTES);
$up_votes = 0;
$down_votes = 0;
$new_data = array(
    $cb_lud_field1_name => $field1_data,
    $cb_lud_field2_name => $field2_data,
    'up_votes' => $up_votes,
    'down_votes' => $down_votes,
    );
$format = array('%s', '%s', '%f', '%f');

if (isset($field1_data) && !empty($field1_data) && isset($field2_data) &&!empty($field2_data)) {
    $wpdb->insert(
        $cb_lud_table, $new_data, $format
    );
}

/*
DISPLAY THE LIST
*/          
//Get the list from the database, and set the variables for display in the output.
$get_list = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT entry_ID, '.$cb_lud_field1_name.' AS "field1", '.$cb_lud_field2_name.' AS "field2", up_votes, down_votes, up_votes - down_votes AS "total_votes"
    FROM '.$cb_lud_table.'
    GROUP BY entry_ID
    ORDER BY total_votes DESC
    ',OBJECT);

//Check if list is null, and if so, set a variable to display a warning. Otherwise, display the list.
if (empty($get_list)) {
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= "<em>Warning: You don't seem to have any records for this list. Why don't you add some now?</em>";
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= $cb_lud_sc_form;
    return $cb_lud_sc_output;
}
else {
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= $cb_lud_sc_form;
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= '</br>';
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= '<table id="cb_lud_list" border="1" cellpadding="10">';
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= '<tr><td align="center"><strong><a id="sort-by-field1" href="">'.$cb_lud_field1_name.'<a></strong></td><td align="center"><strong>'.$cb_lud_field2_name.'</strong></td><td align="center"><strong>Score</strong></td><td align="center"><strong>Vote Up/Down</strong></td></tr>';
        foreach ($get_list as $list_items) {
            $cb_lud_sc_output .= '<tr class="line-items-rows"><td>'.stripslashes($list_items->field1).'</td><td>'.stripslashes($list_items->field2).'</td><td>'.$list_items->total_votes.'</td><td><form id="up-down-arrows-form" action="" method="post"><input class="up-arrow" name="arrow-up-ID-'.$list_items->entry_ID.'" type="image" src="'.$cb_lud_upimg.'" value="'.$list_items->entry_ID.'"/>&nbsp;<input class="down-arrow" name="arrow-down-ID-'.$list_items->entry_ID.'" type="image" src="'.$cb_lud_downimg.'" value="'.$list_items->entry_ID.'"/></form></td></tr>';
            }
    $cb_lud_sc_output .= '</table>';
    return $cb_lud_sc_output;
}
};
/*
END SHORTCODE
*/

/*
*
*
JQUERY/AJAX for SHORTCODE
*
*
*/

/*
CREATE THE JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY
*/
//Create the function that triggers on shortcode.
add_action('cb_lud_scfunc', 'wp_enqueue_scripts');

function cb_lud_scripts(){

function cb_lud_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' >

$(document).ready(function(){
//JQuery for the submission of a new list item.
    $('input.[class$="-arrow"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //put e in function.
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

        if ($(this).hasClass('up-arrow')) {
            var arrowdirection = 'up';
            var entry = $(this).val();
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('down-arrow')) {
            var arrowdirection = 'down';
            var entry = $(this).val();
        }

        var data = {
            action: 'cb_lud_arrow_action',
            arrow: arrowdirection,
            entryID: entry
        };

        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                alert('Thanks for the vote!'); //for debug. Alert is showing! Still not submitting data to database though.
                $('.line-items-rows').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
});
});

</script>
<?php
//End Javascript function.  
}

//Call the javascript function
cb_lud_action_javascript();

/*
*
CREATE THE AJAX
*
*/

/*
ARROW CALLBACK
*/

if( is_admin() )
{
add_action('wp_ajax_cb_lud_arrow_action', 'cb_lud_arrow_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cb_lud_arrow_action', 'cb_lud_arrow_callback');

}
else{
function cb_lud_arrow_callback(){       
    //Redefine basic variables
    global $wpdb;
    $cb_lud_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $cb_lud_table = $cb_lud_prefix . 'cb_list_up_down';

    //New variables from POST
    $cb_lud_entry_id = $_POST['entry'];
    $cb_lud_arrow_direction = $_POST['arrowdirection'];

    if ($cb_lud_arrow_direction == 'up') {
        $wpdb->query('UPDATE '.$cb_lud_table.' SET up_votes=up_votes+1
        WHERE entry_ID='.$cb_lud_entry_id.'');
    }

    else if ($cb_lud_arrow_direction == 'down') {
        $wpdb->query('UPDATE '.$cb_lud_table.' SET down_votes=down_votes+1
        WHERE entry_ID='.$cb_lud_entry_id.'');
    }

die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}       
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cb_lud_scripts');
```

Comment: Note: I changed the $_POST requests to 'arrow' and 'entryID', since this is how they are labeled in the JQuery. Still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution has been to set 'ajaxurl' to the page url in the JQuery script:

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>';
```

Then set the url in ajax to the same:

```
var data = {
            action: 'cb_lud_arrow_action',
            arrow: arrowdirection,
            entryID: entry
        };
$.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                alert('Thanks for the vote!'); //for debug. Alert is showing! Still not submitting data to database though.
                $('.line-items-rows').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
```

This appears to work because I want the JQuery to call the action function only when the Shortcode is being displayed. I therefore hooked the JQuery function into the shortcode, so that it only fires on pages where the shortcode is present.

Now the values are updating to the database fine.